# How to use python-keybinder to get clipboard content

Tags: python, pygtk

I've got two code samples. The first is to get current clipboard content and print it, the second is using python-keybinder to do some action on a hotkey press. I'm stuck with combining those two together. I want my clipboard content to be printed on a hotkey press (i.e. I do a text selection, press a hotkey and this selection is printed). Here's my code:

To get selection:

```
import gtk

def _clipboard_changed(clipboard, event):
    text = clipboard.wait_for_text()
    print text

gtk.clipboard_get(gtk.gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY).connect("owner-change", _clipboard_changed)

gtk.main()
```

To bind a hotkey:

```
import gtk
import keybinder

def callback():
    print "pressed"
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keystr = "<Ctrl>A"
    keybinder.bind(keystr, callback)
    gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Just as a warning I am at work and currently unable to test the code in this answer but it should at least point you in the right direction.*

I assume the problem is that you can't combine the two callbacks.
There are two solutions I can think of. 

1) Use a global to store the clipboard data and read from it the keybinder callback

```
    import gtk
    import keybinder

    cbText = ""

    def keybinder_callback():
        print cbText
        gtk.main_quit()

    def _clipboard_changed(clipboard, event):
        global cbText
        cbText = clipboard.wait_for_text()

    gtk.clipboard_get(gtk.gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY).connect("owner-change", _clipboard_changed)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        keystr = "<Ctrl>A"
        keybinder.bind(keystr, keybinder_callback)
        gtk.main()
```

2) Get rid of the first callback.

```
    import gtk
    import keybinder

    def callback():
        print "pressed"
        clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
        text = clipboard.wait_for_text()
        print text
        gtk.main_quit()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        keystr = "<Ctrl>A"
        keybinder.bind(keystr, callback)
        gtk.main()
```